# sql to html using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

Okay I am really stumped here. On screen.php, I have the database tables showing, and I have an edit button being generated for each database row that is created. The edit button calls a javascript function, which opens a popup html form.

For each row in the database, this is the PHP code that generates the new row in html:

```
$output .= "<tr><td>". $row["name"]. "</td><td>". $row["country"]. "</td><td>". $row["base_nav"]."</td><td>"."<button type='button' rel='tooltip' title='Remove' class='btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button><button onclick='edit();' type='button' rel='tooltip' title='Edit' class='btn btn-warning btn-simple btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>"."</td></tr>";
```

When the user clicks the edit button, that specific row should populate the popup box with the data from that row.

This is my code within the screen.php file.

```
<?php
require 'login_crudentials.php';
$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pword, $database, 3306);
if ($connection ->connect_error) die($connection ->connect_error);
$query = "select * from base";
$result = $connection->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())?>
```

and in the popup html form, under the value parameter I have for example:

```
value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>">
```

The form is completely blank. The data is not being copied over. The yellow button is the edit button that triggers the pop-up. The javascript function is the same for all of the edit buttons being generated though, so maybe this is the issue and maybe each should be unique ?

I've attached an image here for reference as to the edit button and popup form.
[image]

jscript:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var editbasemodal = document.getElementById('editbasemodal');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var editbasespan = document.getElementById("editbaseclose");
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
function editbase(){
    editbasemodal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
editbasespan.onclick = function() {
    editbasemodal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (event.target == editbasemodal) {
        editbasemodal.style.display = "none";
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Show your JavaScript code

Comment: PHP is executed *once*, on the server. The result is delivered to the browser. If you want to copy a row's values into your popup with JavaScript, i.e. on the *client*, you'll have to grab the values from the HTML code generated by PHP. You can no longer expect PHP commands / values to do anything since they do not exist any longer on the client. Unless you're giving each row its own popup? Anyway, we don't see enough of your code.

Comment: @chris G yes each row has an edit button which calls the popup html form

Comment: @datasci I get that. Can you show MORE OF YOUR CODE? Like your entire while loop? And you JavaScript code?

Comment: @ChrisG just posted the javascript at the bottom of my original post

Comment: That code suggests you have a single popup. However you say your popup has `value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>">`, is that inside the while loop or not?

Comment: @ChrisG  No the value parameter is place in the html form. So this is a hidden form filed, and when the edit button is clicked javascript is used to open the html form. For the first field in the form, this is where I have the value tag

Comment: @ChrisG Maybe I can use javascript to paste each row to the form fields when the edit button is pressed on any row?

Comment: @datasci Why do you keep talking like I had never posted my first comment? This is what I suggested from the start.

Comment: @chris g I know how to access the element text for each row, but im not sure how to copy the data to the form field value parameter

Comment: `document.querySelector('#editbasemodal input[name=country]').value = elementText;`

Comment: @ChrisG worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('#editbasemodal input[name=country]').value = elementText;